# videoangular--How to have multiple video players in one screen?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, videogular

Hi so Im using this angularjs framework "videogular" and have no problem creating a single player, but I dont know how to create multiple players in one screen since apparently each player requires a controller

[image]

```
sample code here:
http://codepen.io/2fdevs/pen/KmDIE
```

Answer (score 0):

Each player needs a different config file but not a different controller.

Maybe this other answer could be useful:

[stop other video that is playing in background on play the new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827732/stop-other-video-that-is-playing-in-background-on-play-the-new-one)