# How to access videogular's API inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, videogular

I need multiple [videogular](http://www.videogular.com/) videos on a page, each one with a button beneath to start the video. In order to have a scope for every single video I need to put them into directives, as discussed [here](https://github.com/videogular/videogular/issues/59).

I'm not able to access videogular's API though. I'm pretty sure the problem is the onPlayerReady function. There is quite a lot of [documentation](http://www.videogular.com/tutorials/videogular-api/) on the API, I didn't manage to get it to work though.

**Directive:**

```
.directive("topmVideogularDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: "=",
            config: "="
        },
        template: '<videogular vg-plays-inline="true" vg-player-ready="onPlayerReady"><vg-media vg-src="data" vg-native-controls="false" vg-loop="true"></vg-media></videogular><button ng-click="test()">test</button>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.$API = null;
            scope.onPlayerReady = function($API) {
                console.log("tell me you're there");
                scope.$API = $API;
            };
            scope.test = function(){
                scope.$API.play();
            };   
        }
    };
```

Full code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMKKbX

There is also another maybe related question on SO: [stop other video that is playing in background on play the new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827732/stop-other-video-that-is-playing-in-background-on-play-the-new-one)

And a discusson on Github as mentioned above: https://github.com/videogular/videogular/issues/59