# Managing videogular API when two videos are on the page

Tags: angularjs, videogular

I have a site where I need to show two different videos on it and I need to be able to do some actions with the videogular API.

The thing is that when I share the $API from the view to the controller using vgPlayerReady($API) the method I call to one video is applied in both! For example I want to mute one video but when I call setVolume() with the API returned, both videos get muted. 
Is this a known issue?
Is there other way to mute just one video?

Comment: I think that you're looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827732/stop-other-video-that-is-playing-in-background-on-play-the-new-one

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this didn't wok. The issue is that the change I apply to the API is applied too for the other video wen I refresh the page. So one I refresh the page both videos are muted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I found to fix this was to setVolume(0) when the video that I want to be muted is ready to be played, and setVolume(1) when the video I want with volume is ready to be played.
The volume property didn't work for me.